# ValueError in Django Python Forum application

Tags: python, django, cascade, forum, valueerror

I'm trying to create a form where users can add a new topic within a category. Then the users will be able to comment on each topic. Everything was working up until I tried adding the form page for new_topic

The error I receive:

ValueError at /new_topic/
The view speak_space.views.new_topic didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Heres the code for my view.py and urls.py files:

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Category
from .models import Topic
from .forms import TopicForm

def index(request):
    """The home page for speak_space"""
    return render(request, 'speak_space/index.html')

def categories(request):
    """Show all categories."""
    categories = Category.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'speak_space/categories.html', context)

def category(request, category_id):
    """Show a single category(tribe) and all of its topics(convos)."""
    category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
    topics = category.topic_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'category': category, 'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'speak_space/category.html', context)

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics within a category(tribe)."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'speak_space/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic(convo/post) and all of it's replies."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'speak_space/topic.html', context)

def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new conversation topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('speak_space:topics')

        # Display a blank or invalid form.
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'speak_space/new_topic.html', context)
```

and heres my url file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'speak_space'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    # Page that shows all categories
    path('categories/', views.categories, name='categories'),

    # Profile page for a category
    path('categories/<int:category_id>/', views.category, name='category'),

    # Page that shows all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),

    # Detail page for a single topic(conversation)
    # Where you go after you click on someones post
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),

    # Page for adding a new conversation topic
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
 ]
```

and my forms page:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new_topic` view doesn't return anything in case of GET request. You shoud make `return` statement common:

```
def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new conversation topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('speak_space:topics')

    # The changes are here, now return will work for all requests types POST and GET
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'speak_space/new_topic.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deindent the following lines

```
# Display a blank or invalid form.
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'speak_space/new_topic.html', context)
```

inside your `new_topic` method.